Nuxt 3: Entire Project Rebuilds on Any Component Change – Configuration Issue?
I’m working on a Nuxt 3 project, and I’ve encountered a problem where the entire project rebuilds whenever I make any change to a component, regardless of whether it’s a change in the TailwindCSS styling or a small update in the component’s logic. This behavior is causing significant delays in my development process.
Interestingly, I recall there being times when this did not happen, and only the affected parts of the project would rebuild, which was much faster and more efficient. I’m wondering what might be causing this issue and how I can prevent the entire project from rebuilding every time.
Additionally, in the console, I keep seeing repeated messages like this:
ℹ Directory components/ created
ℹ Restarting Nuxt...
Does anyone have any insights into what might be causing this, and how I can adjust my configuration to stop these full rebuilds?
I tried making small changes to individual components, expecting only the modified parts to rebuild. However, the entire project rebuilds every time, which is unexpected. I was hoping for faster build times with just the affected components being updated.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
